# /dev/sda1 is either busy or mounted to /cdrom and umount doesn't fix it

Tags: grub2, partitioning, mount, live-usb

So, I accidentally password protected my grub2 and set a password (incorrectly, so it doesn't let me enter anymore). To solve that, I tried booting from a liveUSB and this is what I did and what happened:

- `sudo mkdir /mnt/hdd`
- `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd`

That gave me the output: `/dev/sda1 is already mounted or /mnt/hdd busy` and `/dev/sda1 is already mounted on /cdrom`.

So, to solve that is tried umount and a big number of options. And when `umount` "worked" I tried to mount `/dev/sda1` to `/mnt/hdd` again and it worked. But then, when I tried the final step (`sudo chroot /mnt/hdd`) for dropping in to root shell from LiveUSB it wasn't able to find `/bin/bash` (basically, something went wrong).

Does anybody know the solution to this problem?

Comment: `/dev/sda1` is probably the disc you booted your system with.  Reboot to the LiveCD, and run a program like `gparted` or `parted -l` and see if you can see what your hard drive is.  The hard drive might be /dev/sdb1

Comment: Thanks, :D! Although the hard drive was /dev/mmcblk0p1, that really was a spot on comment!

Comment: FWIW, some new SSDs have device filenames of the form `/dev/mmcblk?p?`, whereas disks (and SSDs) using the older SATA, SCSI, and even IDE interfaces have device filenames of the form `/dev/sd??`. (A few years ago, IDE and some SATA disks had names of `/dev/hd??`, but that's become rare to nonexistent with the kernel options used when compiling modern Ubuntu distributions.)